# Memory Leak detection in Lazarus - again

Tags: memory-leaks, lazarus, freepascal

I am using Lazarus 2.0.4 on Windows 10.

Trying to track memory leaks in a quite large project I tried to familiarize myself with the heaptrc and lineinfo units/compiler switches -gh and -gl.

While this gives me some information that there is a leak somewhere, I could not figure out how to pinpoint the exact location. I put together this quite basic leaking code which will leak 4 bytes every time the button is pressed. Upon exit of the program I get this:

[image: Heaptrc info about memory leak]

While from the trace I see that there is a 4 byte memory leak, I cannot see any useful reference where to look for the leaking code. I see that the code was within the click handler of a TButton, but this isn't very useful, since there may be many Buttons.

Any way to get a reference to the exact location (line 42)?

Comment: Did you set optimization to -O- ?

Comment: No. Under "compiling and linking" by default Lazarus (Debug Config) has set Optimizations to Step 1 (fast, debugger-friendly) (-O1). Following your idea I have also tried Step 0 (no further optimizations), didn't make any difference. I did also try to set all options under the "Verbosity" tab, didn't make any difference either.

Comment: Your test code is badly flawed. First, `Longint` is a simple ordinal type, so you don't use `New` to allocate memory for it. Second, you first call `New(P1);` to (inappropriately) allocate 4 bytes of memory, and then immediately call `New(P1);` again (inappropriately), which discards (inappropriately) the 4 bytes you allocated with the first call (leaving that 4 bytes orphaned). Then you call `Dispose(P1);` which frees the second 4 bytes you allocated, leaving the first 4 bytes still orphaned, which is your *leak*.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot agree to any of those statements. 1) the code is meant to have a flaw, since the question is about a mechanism detecting such flaws. 2) You noted that P1 and P2 are of type POINTER to integer? 3) Otherwise you are right, the two New statements do indeed cause a memory leak, because thhat is what the demo is meant to do. 4) In this sense, the test code is not at all flawed, it is you not understanding what the code sample is about at all.